# Como fazer uma aplicação x64 se conectar a um driver ODBC 32bits?

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

Tenho uma aplicação x64 escrita em C# com *.Net Framework 4* que precisa se conectar ao driver Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.

Ao utilizar esse driver com a aplicação em modo x86, funciona normalmente essa conexão. Porém ao utilizar a aplicação em modo x64 ele não consegue se conectar e apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Gostaria de saber uma forma da minha aplicação x64 conseguir abrir uma conexão `OdbcConnection` utilizando esse driver.

**Obs**: Eu preciso realizar a conexão com esse driver para não precisar utilizar a configuração do arquivo TNS dentro do cliente.

Comment: Eu acho que a única forma é fazer sua aplicação rodar em 32 bits. Isto seria um problema para você?

Comment: @bigown Seria sim. Não existe outra possibilidade? Ou você saberia como eu consigo realizar uma conexão com o banco Oracle 11g sem a necessidade da configuração do arquivo TNS?

Comment: Imediatamente não vejo outra solução mas se achar alguma coisa, eu posto.

Comment: @bigown como não tens certeza da solução, poderia dar um voto para a pergunta? Assim ela entra em evidência para que outros users também possam ajudar. valeu

Comment: Acho que psNytrancez faz esta pergunta porque ele tem um computador em 32bits, com a base de dados, e como os novo computador sao em 64, o 32 não funciona mas...
Eu tenho um amigo na França que tem o mesmo problema. Depois de muitas pesquisas... não parece ter solução 'perfeita'.
Aqui tem um resposta e tem varias outras sobre o mesmo problema :
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3577044

Comment: @Peter O que acontece é o seguinte: Existe um driver odbc chamado "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" (MDAC) na qual ele só existe na versão 32bits. Minha aplicação roda em modo x64, diante disso ela não enxerga o driver citado. Gostaria de saber se é possível a aplicação x64 enxergar esse driver x86 citado anteriomente.

Comment: Eu sei que ele existe somente en 32 bits. Infelizmente. Vou buscar a respota do meu amigo Frances, mas acho que não tem solução..
Achei uma ponto estranho:
 - A  v. 32 bits de Odbcad32.exe esta em %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64.
- A v. 64 bits de Odbcad32.exe esta na pasta %systemdrive%\Windows\System32.
O que quer dizer que tem os 2 ???????!!!!

Comment: @Peter esses caminhos que vc citou é somente para acessar o Administrador de fonte de dados ODBC 32bits e 64bits. Foge um pouco da pergunta em si.

Comment: É possível colocar um código de como é realizada a conexão no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez essa pergunta é antiga, eu consigui resolver por outras vias, nem no projeto eu estou mais, porém não consegui realizar esse tipo de conexão. Enfim... era um: OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnectString)

Answer (score 1):

Para acesso a uma base de dados qualquer aplicativo deve utilizar um cliente, do SO ou do fornecedor da base de dados. Portanto se tua aplicação roda em 64 bits o cliente deve ser 64 bits também.

A solução é instalar o driver Oracle para 64 bits.

[EDIT]
Parece que existe uma forma de você distribuir um cliente Oracle, junto de sua aplicação. Veja este link [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). Há algumas restrições. O tamanho do módulo chega a 120 Mb e deve ser distribuído um pacote para cada plataforma 32/64 bits.

Comment: @Isalamon estou utilizando o driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" justamente pq não precisa da configuração do Oracle no cliente e nem a necessidade da configuração do arquivo do tnsnames. O driver citado pode ser encontrado aqui: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793

Comment: @psNytrancez, o MDAC deixou de existir como distribuição para sistemas operacionais Vista e superior. O driver em questão passou a ser fornecido pelo criador do banco somente.

Comment: @Isalamon, ok. Independente disso minha dúvida é com relação a uma aplicação x64 acessar um driver ODBC x86. Visto que hoje eu possuo esse driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" e consigo acessar quando a aplicação é x86.

Comment: @psNytrancez, processos 64 bits não podem executar código 32 bits. Se absolutamente necessário usar a versão 32 bits, a única forma que vejo é criando um módulo COM, 32 bits, que sirva de interface ao "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle". Registre o módulo no COM+ e assim o código 64 bits poderá acessar o driver indiretamente.